# Auto unmount when removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, riot.js

Consider the following example:

```js
riot.mount('clock')
setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log("removing from dom")
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("clock")[0];
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  riot.update();
}, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/riot/2.5.0/riot+compiler.min.js">
</script>
<script type="riot/tag">
  <clock>
      <p>{ time }</p>
      
      this.time = new Date();
      tick() {
        this.update({ time: new Date() })
      }
      var timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000)
      this.on("unmount",() => {
       console.log("unmounted")
        clearInterval(timer)
      });
      this.on("update",() => {
        console.log("on update");
      });
      this.tick();
  </clock>
</script>

<clock></clock>
```

where we mount a tag, then remove it using normal DOM methods. In this case, it can be seen that although the tag is no longer in existence, it hasn't been unmounted and therefore the disposal code in the `unmount` event handler is not run.

I could use DOM MutationObserver to handle this case, but I am wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `parentNode` on update and call `unmount` if it doesn't exist.

```js
riot.mount('clock')
setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log("removing from dom")
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("clock")[0];
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  riot.update();
}, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/riot/2.5.0/riot+compiler.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  riot.mixin("autoUnmount", {
    init: function() {
      this.on("update",() => {
        if (!this.root.parentNode) {
          this.unmount();
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
<script type="riot/tag">
  <clock>
      <p>{ time }</p>
      
      this.mixin("autoUnmount");
      this.time = new Date();
      tick() {
        this.update({ time: new Date() })
      }
      var timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000)
      this.on("unmount",() => {
       console.log("unmounted")
        clearInterval(timer)
      });
      this.on("update",() => {
        console.log("on update");
      });
      this.tick();
  </clock>
</script>

<clock></clock>
```